# PHP REgex using preg_match all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

```
<OPTION value=a.a.>Afaceri</OPTION>
<OPTION value=a.b.>Mass Media</OPTION>
<OPTION value=a.c.>Publicitate</OPTION>
<OPTION value=b.a.>Agricultura</OPTION>
```

i want to extract "Afaceri,Mass Media,Publicitate,Agricultura" from this html code with an php regex 
how can i do?

Comment: `preg_match_all('#<option[^>]*>(.*?)</option>#i', $string, $m); print_r($m);` enjoy the downvotes ... Hint: html parser, dom.

Comment: _Note:_ tags should be written with lower-case chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html and regexes can be a bit slippery; an alternative solution, assuming that your fragment of html is formatted as above with a newline after each option could be to use `strip_tags()`

```
<?php
// your html fragment
$html = "<OPTION value=a.a.>Afaceri</OPTION>
<OPTION value=a.b.>Mass Media</OPTION>
<OPTION value=a.c.>Publicitate</OPTION>
<OPTION value=b.a.>Agricultura</OPTION>";

// explode by newline
$opts = explode(PHP_EOL, $html);

// use strip_tags on each element
$names = array_map(function($opt) {
    return strip_tags($opt);
}, $opts);

// done
var_dump($names);
```

Should yield:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'Afaceri' (length=7)
  1 => string 'Mass Media' (length=10)
  2 => string 'Publicitate' (length=11)
  3 => string 'Agricultura' (length=11)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regular expression without any conditions on the string between the  tags.

```
$names = preg_match_all('/<OPTION.*?>(.*?)<\/OPTION>/i', $string);
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `<>`, also the `i` modifier may be a good option :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, we often (almost always) suggest to use [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and give link to the manual but I've not seen much examples.

While `regex` is capable to parse html it is not the right tool. You need to use some dom parser to avoid head-ache with malformed html. PHP gives nice [API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to work with.

For example, you should do something like this with [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to get desired output:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<OPTION value=a.a.>Afaceri</OPTION>
<OPTION value=a.b.>Mass Media</OPTION>
<OPTION value=a.c.>Publicitate</OPTION>
<OPTION value=b.a.>Agricultura</OPTION>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('option');

$result = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $result[] = $node->nodeValue;
}

var_dump($result);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/miuZxl)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this: `/<OPTION [^>]+>([^<]+)<\/OPTION>/`

That means: Match the text "<OPTION " followed by one or more characters that are not ">", then match that ">" and capture one or more characters that are not "<", followed by "</OPTION>".

Btw, if you want to avoid escaping, to make the regex more clean, you could use a different delimiter, like this: `#<OPTION [^>]+>([^<]+)</OPTION>#`